# Function of scrolling up not being called from DidSelectItem UITabBarController Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

```
    @property (nonatomic, assign) Home *VC;


-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
    {
        NSUInteger indexOfTab = [[tabBar items] indexOfObject:item];

                NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)indexOfTab);

            UITableView *tableView = self.VC.tableView;

            UIEdgeInsets tableInset = tableView.contentInset;

            [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(- tableInset.left, - tableInset.top) animated:YES];

    }
```

The NSLOG works fine but the logic to scroll up the tableView doesnt get called at all.

Comment: `tableView` is nil? Is `VC` the same object as the one you see on screen? For instance, what logs the pointer of `self.VC.tableView` (here) and `self.tableView` (in Home file code)?

Comment: You were right, it was logging as null. Why? the table view is populated?

Comment: How did you set `VC`?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) Home *VC;

Comment: i changed it to     `Home * vc = [[Home alloc] init];` but the code to scroll up doesn't do anything.

Comment: That's because you are creating a NEW object of class Home. You are not retrieving the one already allocated/initialized and all set up that you see on your screen.

Comment: @Larme how should I retrieve it then?

Comment: You could use NSNotification to tell your `Home` view controller that it need to scroll.

Comment: Didn't think of that!, thanks i figured it out. works flawlessly.